# Render Partial results in 'can't dup NilClass'

Tags: ruby, middleman

Currently in Middleman when trying to render out another file while utilizing the SLIM engine I get an issue when trying to run...

```
== render :markdown, '/markdowns/privacy.md'
```

it returns an error of...

```
can't dup NilClass
```

No idea why, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could provide more relevant data - maybe what's in 'privacy.md', what's the full stack trace?

Comment: shouldn't it be `'markdowns/privacy.md'` (relative path) instead of `'/markdowns/privacy.md'` (absolute path)?

Comment: Unfortunately, Middleman is short on meaningful error messages. You are unlikely receive help on this unless you provide a demonstration of your issue as a minimal Middleman project shared on Github.